# Memory leak when using Apollo on react native

Tags: react-native, websocket, apollo-client

When using ApolloClient in our React NAtive app, we get a memory leak that crashes teh app within 30 seconds of the app making the first apollo request.

Overall teh code we use is teh following:

```
const logErrorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  reportError(
    new Error(`Error Apollo ${operation.operationName}`),
    (report) => {
      const _params = {
        data: {
          operationName: operation.operationName,
          extensions: operation.extensions,
          query: operation.query,
          variables: operation.variables,
          conext: operation.getContext(),
          graphQLErrors,
          networkError,
        } as any,
      };
      report.addMetadata('report', _params);
    }
  );

});

const withToken = setContext(async () => {
  const user = auth().currentUser;
  let token = '';
  try {
    if (user) {
      token = await user.getIdToken();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    consoleDebug('error la', error);
  }
  return { token, uid: user?.uid || '' };
});

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const { token, uid } = operation.getContext();
  operation.setContext(() => ({
    headers: {
      ...createRequestParams(uid, 'apollo', operation.operationName),
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token as string}` : '',
    },
  }));
  return forward(operation);
});

const retryLink = new RetryLink({
  delay: (retryNumber) => {
    const delay = Math.pow(2, retryNumber) * 300;
    const randomSum = delay * 0.2 * Math.random(); // 0-20% of the delay
    return delay + randomSum;
  },
  attempts: {
    max: 4,
    retryIf: async (error, operation) => {
      if (error.statusCode === 401) {
        const user = auth().currentUser;
        const { uid } = operation.getContext();
        let token = '';
        if (user) {
          token = await user.getIdToken(true);
          bugsnag.leaveBreadcrumb('new refreshToken apollo');
        }
        if (token) {
          operation.setContext({
            headers: {
              ...createRequestParams(uid, 'apollo', operation.operationName),
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          });
          return true;
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
});
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  retryLink,
  logErrorLink,
  withToken,
  authMiddleware.concat(persistedQueriesLink.concat(httpLink)),
]);
const linkPayment = ApolloLink.from([
  retryLink,
  logErrorLink,
  withToken,
  authMiddleware.concat(persistedQueriesLink.concat(httpLinkPayment)),
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  name: `mobile-${Platform.OS}`,
  version: DeviceInfo.getReadableVersion(),
  // link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink)
  link,
});

async processUser(data: any) {
    try {
      await client.mutate({
        mutation: updateUserMutation,
        variables: {
          data,
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('NEw apollo user', e);
    }
  }
```

as soon as `processUser` is called the memory usage for up. (note that this also happens with a query, not just mutations)

The native stack for where teh memory leak is happening is:

```
0 libc++abi.dylib operator new(unsigned long)
   1 Choose void* std::__1::__libcpp_operator_new<unsigned long>(unsigned long) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:235
   2 Choose std::__1::__libcpp_allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:261
   3 Choose std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*> >::allocate(unsigned long) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:870
   4 Choose std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*> > >::allocate(std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*> >&, unsigned long) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator_traits.h:260
   5 Choose std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*>, std::__1::__hash_node_destructor<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*> > > > std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<folly::dynamic, std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<folly::dynamic, std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic> > >::__construct_node<std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>&&, std::__1::tuple<>&&) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:2455
   6 Choose std::__1::pair<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*>*>, bool> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<folly::dynamic, std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<folly::dynamic, std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic> > >::__emplace_unique_impl<std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>&&, std::__1::tuple<>&&) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:2137
   7 Choose std::__1::pair<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*>*>, bool> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<folly::dynamic, std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<folly::dynamic, std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic> > >::__emplace_unique<std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>&&, std::__1::tuple<>&&) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:1096
   8 Choose std::__1::pair<std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*>*> >, bool> std::__1::unordered_map<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<folly::dynamic const, folly::dynamic> > >::emplace<std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>&&, std::__1::tuple<>&&) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:1158
   9 Choose auto std::__1::pair<std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*>*> >, bool> folly::f14::detail::F14BasicMap<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<folly::dynamic const, folly::dynamic> > >::emplace<std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>&&, std::__1::tuple<>&&)::'lambda'(auto&, auto&&...)::operator()<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(auto&, auto&&...) const /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14MapFallback.h:215
  10 Choose _ZN5folly6detail22callWithKeyAndPairArgsINS_7dynamicES2_ZNS_3f146detail11F14BasicMapIS2_S2_NS0_13DynamicHasherENS0_15DynamicKeyEqualENSt3__19allocatorINS8_4pairIKS2_S2_EEEEE7emplaceIJRKNS8_21piecewise_construct_tENS8_5tupleIJRNS8_12basic_stringIcNS8_11char_traitsIcEENS9_IcEEEEEEENSJ_IJEEEEEENSA_INS8_19__hash_map_iteratorINS8_15__hash_iteratorIPNS8_11__hash_nodeINS8_17__hash_value_typeIS2_S2_EEPvEEEEEEbEEDpOT_EUlRT_DpOT0_E_SO_JSP_EJEEEDaOT1_RKT2_ONSJ_IJDpT3_EEEONSJ_IJDpT4_EEE /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/Util.h:125
  11 Choose _ZN5folly6detail20callWithExtractedKeyINS_7dynamicES2_NS_3f146detail11F14BasicMapIS2_S2_NS0_13DynamicHasherENS0_15DynamicKeyEqualENSt3__19allocatorINS8_4pairIKS2_S2_EEEEE11UsableAsKeyESD_ZNSE_7emplaceIJRKNS8_21piecewise_construct_tENS8_5tupleIJRNS8_12basic_stringIcNS8_11char_traitsIcEENS9_IcEEEEEEENSK_IJEEEEEENSA_INS8_19__hash_map_iteratorINS8_15__hash_iteratorIPNS8_11__hash_nodeINS8_17__hash_value_typeIS2_S2_EEPvEEEEEEbEEDpOT_EUlRT_DpOT0_E_SQ_JELi0EEEDaRT2_OT3_SH_ONSK_IJT4_EEEONSK_IJDpT5_EEE /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/Util.h:155
  12 Choose std::__1::pair<std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*>*> >, bool> folly::f14::detail::F14BasicMap<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<folly::dynamic const, folly::dynamic> > >::emplace<std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>, std::__1::tuple<> >(std::__1::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>&&, std::__1::tuple<>&&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14MapFallback.h:203
  13 Choose std::__1::enable_if<folly::detail::EligibleForHeterogeneousInsert<folly::dynamic, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>::value, std::__1::pair<std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic>, void*>*> >, bool> >::type folly::f14::detail::F14BasicMap<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<folly::dynamic const, folly::dynamic> > >::try_emplace<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14MapFallback.h:268
  14 Choose std::__1::enable_if<folly::detail::EligibleForHeterogeneousInsert<folly::dynamic, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>::value, folly::dynamic&>::type folly::f14::detail::F14BasicMap<folly::dynamic, folly::dynamic, folly::detail::DynamicHasher, folly::detail::DynamicKeyEqual, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<folly::dynamic const, folly::dynamic> > >::operator[]<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14MapFallback.h:356
  15 Choose std::__1::enable_if<!(std::is_convertible<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::__wrap_iter<folly::dynamic*> >::value), void>::type folly::dynamic::insert<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::nullptr_t>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::nullptr_t&&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/dynamic-inl.h:834
  16 Choose facebook::jsi::dynamicFromValue(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/jsi/JSIDynamic.cpp:187
  17 Choose facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callNativeModules(facebook::jsi::Value const&, bool) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor/jsireact/JSIExecutor.cpp:420
  18 Choose facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callFunction(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, folly::dynamic const&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor/jsireact/JSIExecutor.cpp:270
  19 Choose std::__1::__function::__value_func<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*&&) const /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1885
  20 Choose std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*) const /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:2560
  21 Choose facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8::operator()() const /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact/NativeToJsBridge.cpp:310
  22 Choose decltype(std::__1::forward<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8&>(fp)()) std::__1::__invoke<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8&>(facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8&) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:3694
  23 Choose void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void, true>::__call<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8&>(facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8&) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:348
  24 Choose std::__1::__function::__alloc_func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8>, void ()>::operator()() /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1558
  25 Choose std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8>, void ()>::operator()() /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1732
  26 Choose std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1885
  27 Choose std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:2560
  28 Choose facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/React/CxxModule/RCTCxxUtils.mm:74
  29 Choose facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTMessageThread.mm:69
  30 Choose std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1885
  31 Choose std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:2560
  32 Choose invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void ()>) /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTMessageThread.mm:45
  33 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
  34 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
  35 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
  36 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
  37 Choose +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] /Users/otusweb/Projects/AppChoose/node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm:367
  38 Foundation __NSThread__start__
  39 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start
  40 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start
```

Link to github issue: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9079